# What is the term for an anthropomorphic animal that fits a certain role or profession? (ex. a scholarly owl, dalmatian firefighter)

Tags: animals

I am struggling to find out what to look for.  My goal is to find a list of stereotypical anthropomorphic animals, but I am having trouble searching because I don't know what the term is called.  For example an Owl is usually smart and scholarly.  A fox is usually sly and thieving.

Is there a term for this?

Comment: The closest thing I can come up with is "mascot."

Comment: I think the best way to describe what I'm looking for is to compare it to Animal Crossing.  The fox sells counterfeit goods, the owl runs a museum, the policemen are dogs...

Comment: I understand the concept, but I cannot for the life of me think of a word for it. That's both frustrating and really cool.  Good job.

Comment: There is a list of Animal stereotypes [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypes_of_animals), but I am looking for something exclusive to animals that are portrayed as people ala Animal Crossing.

Answer (score 11):

I have not found a specific term for what you describe, but this tendency is explained historically on Wikipedia, with a list of examples in alphabetical order.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypes_of_animals

Comment: +1 because that seems to be the core idea - TVTropes has [Animal Stereotypes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimalStereotypes), for example.

Comment: @Izkata I think TVTropes is considered authoritative for such questions. You should offer that as an answer, I'd upvote. Just please don't link to it.

Comment: I did try finding something on TVTropes but since every article has a clever name, it was difficult to tell if they actually had one like what I am thinking.

Comment: I like the designation "Animal Stereotype" because it gets straight to the point and is precise in its description. Kudos.

Comment: @JohnO I'm not so sure it should be separate, since it's pretty much just saying the same thing...

Answer (score 4):

A list of [totemic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totem) animals is likely as close as you'll get to what you seek.
 Here's one such list at whats-your-sign.com: [Animal Totem Meanings and Animal Symbolism.](http://www.whats-your-sign.com/animal-totems.html) I'd take it in with several grains of salt.